# Fetch data from database after equal time interval

Tags: php, mysql

```
$host= "localhost";
$user= "xxxx";
$pass= "xxxx";
$db="xxxx";

$connect= mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
if (!$connect)die ("Cannot connect!");
mysql_select_db($db, $connect);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xxxx");
if($result){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $url = $row['xxxx'];
    echo $url;
    }
}
```

above code is working fine.

I want to show each result in 5 sec time interval

```
row1    //wait 5 sec
row2   //wait 5 sec
row3   //wait 5 sec
row4   //wait 5 sec
```

is there any way I can do that.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PHP sleep function to delay execution

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

However you should not be doing this to delay the output of your page in most cases. Use of JavaScript client code is recommended to modify User Interface experience.